# How to check wether http2 is implemented and working on my website?

Tags: apache, http2, http-1.1

I want to check whether http/2 is implemented on my website or not. When I check through https://tools.keycdn.com/ it says http2 is implemented but the typing curl -I  in cmd gives the ouptut:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 17:02:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 17:02:47 GMT
X-Magento-Tags: FPC
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
...
```

Which one is correct is http2 implemented or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure curl is requesting via HTTP2?

try using `--http2`, from [this page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html) on the curl website:

> curl offers the --http2 command line option to enable use of HTTP/2.

Comment: I just typed that into the cmd and that returns : 
curl: (1) Unsupported protocol

Comment: So you are using an older version of curl that doesn’t support HTTP/2, hence why it falls back to HTTP/1.1 hence why you are seeing a difference between that and the online tool.